# Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm using Glassfish 3.0.1, JVM 1.6.0_21 on Windows XP Pro;

I don't know exactly what has changed in my environment but I get this stacktrace as soon as I try to deploy an enterprise application (ejb module + app client module).

There is nothing running on port 3820, except Glassfish... I checked with netstat with the server stopped and the server started.

What could be the cause of this? Some internal process conflict?

Any tips on how I can debug this further?

```
WARNING: Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory
SEVERE: iiop.createsocket_exception
WARNING: Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory
SEVERE: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:106)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:106)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:72)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSSLServerSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:402)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createServerSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:281)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:91)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:247)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:264)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:131)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.initialize(POAImpl.java:474)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.makeRootPOA(POAImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAFactory$1.evaluate(POAFactory.java:279)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.closure.Future.evaluate(Future.java:57)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.LocalResolverImpl.resolve(LocalResolverImpl.java:51)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:55)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1289)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.naming.cosnaming.TransientNameService.initialize(TransientNameService.java:122)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.naming.cosnaming.TransientNameService.<init>(TransientNameService.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.PEORBConfigurator.configure(PEORBConfigurator.java:154)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBConfiguratorImpl.runUserConfigurators(ORBConfiguratorImpl.java:191)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBConfiguratorImpl.configure(ORBConfiguratorImpl.java:176)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:579)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:680)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:666)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:612)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:83)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:189)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:810)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:558)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.<init>(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:136)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.CMCSingletonContainer.<init>(CMCSingletonContainer.java:73)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:207)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

WARNING: Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory
WARNING: Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory
SEVERE: "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create IIOP listener on the specified host/port: all interfaces/3820"
```

**EDIT**
Here it's exactly what I tried:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\b.tanase>netstat -p tcp -ano | findstr :3820

asadmin> start-domain domain1
Waiting for DAS to start ...
Started domain: domain1
Domain location: D:\java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1
Log file: D:\java\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
Admin port for the domain: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.

C:\Documents and Settings\b.tanase>netstat -p tcp -ano | findstr :3820

asadmin> deploy d:/java/projects/netbeans-projects/CountingSystem/dist/CountingS
ystem.ear
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CommandException: remote failure: Exception while l
oading the app : java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
 : java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error


Command deploy failed.

C:\Documents and Settings\b.tanase>netstat -p tcp -ano | findstr :3820
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3820           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2428
```

As you can see there's nothing listening on port 3820 until the deployment failes (before EJB Container initialization error I get in the server log the stacktrace posted at the beggining of the post)

Comment: Did you try using another port?

Comment: changin ports works. I had to change for SSL & SSL_MUTUALAUTH. The question still remains, why does this happen?

Comment: Did you check port 3700 as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I notice you are using windows, which is particularly bad about using low port numbers for outgoing sockets. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812873) for how to reserve the port number that you want to rely on using for glassfish.

Comment: Thanks for the link; could be useful. Do you think you could elaborate on "windows ... is particularly bad about using low port numbers ..." or give me a link for further reading?

Comment: @Bogdan There's another stack overflow question that gives a bit more detail, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630009/how-can-i-work-around-winxp-using-ports-1025-5000-as-ephemeral

Comment: thanks for the link. This seems to be the most likely cause for what happend. I'll keep it in mind when I'll bump into it again.

Comment: @MrPotes: 1024 is the lower limit regarding 'low port numbers'

Answer (score 47):

Your local port 443 / 8181 / 3820  is used.

If you are on linux/unix:

- use `netstat -an` and `lsof -n`  to check who is using this port

If you are on windows

- use `netstat -an` and [`tcpview`](http://live.sysinternals.com/Tcpview.exe) to check.

Comment: According to netstat & tcpview there's nothing running on port 3820 BEFORE running glassfish & trying to deploy the application. See my update

Comment: tcpview saved my life. +1. It helps to know that tcpview can kill the service that using the port you need.

Comment: In my case an instance of my of program was not closed properly (eclipse restart did not help). In this kind of case it could be easier to first look in task manager and simply kill any JVM instances that you know should not be running.

Answer (score 5):

on windows open a cmd.exe window with administrator permissions and use `netstat -a -b -o`
you will get the id of the proccess that holds your port and be able to kill it using task manager.

Answer (score 1):

as the exception says there is already another server running on the same port. you can either kill that service or change glassfish to run on another poet

Answer (score 0):

The logged error does say that port 3820 is the problem, but I would suggest investigating **all** the ports that your app is trying to listen on.  I ran into this problem and the issue was a port that I'd forgotten about - not the "main" one that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, under Windows, [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is fantastic for observing the existing TCP/IP connections for each process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)** utility.

Try to find in the *localport* column is there any process worked on *"busy"* port. Right click and end the process. Then try to start the *Tomcat*.

Its really works for me.

Answer (score 0):

My answer does 100% fit to this problem, but I want to document my solution and the trap behind it, since the Exception is the same.

My port was always in use testing a Jetty in a Junit testcase. Problem was Google's code pro on Eclipse, which, I guess, was testing in the background and thus starting jetty before me all the time.
Workaround: let Eclipse open *.java files always w/ the Java editor instead of Google's Junit editor. That seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem mostly occurs because there could be another istance of the code running, from some previous tests you did most probably. Find out and close any other instance or if it is ok, try restarting the server.

Comment: How do you close another instance?