# Running Client Server program in java

Tags: networking, client-server

I have written a simple client server application in java. When i try to run the client on the server I get the below exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
    at DateServer.main(DateServer.java:8)

I have added all the jar files checked everything how do I remove this exception to execute my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.Socket;

class DateClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = Integer.parseInt("415");
    Socket server = new Socket(host, port);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(server.getInputStream());
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
```

}

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

class DateServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(415);
    while (true) {
        Socket incoming = s.accept();
        System.out.println(incoming);
        PrintWriter toClient = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream());
        toClient.println(new Date());
        toClient.flush();
        incoming.close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just use any random port without knowing that it's in use or free.

Use netstat -an to check which ports are in use and use one of those which are free.
(For windows, use netstat -an in cmd)

Edit: Take a look at below links, one of these must help you
[How do I resolve the "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind)

[Address already in use: JVM_Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714957/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind)

Comment: Even after I kill the process the issue remains the same.

Comment: Which process are you killing? Is the serversocket 415 free or being used by some other process? For being on a safer side, I would suggest to first look for a free port and then use it in your server.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API, a BindException

`Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and 
port. Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned`

Basically, that port could be in use by another process, even perhaps by another instance of the same application due to an unclean shutdown. This link may help you troubleshoot.

Note:

The posted results of running the netstat -an command seems to verify that port 8085 is in use by multiple processes, which would result in the BindException that you're encountering

Comment: so how do i remove this exception

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this issue quite a few times. The socket, in your server presumably, still has the port you specified in use or `bound` by another process (in my case, I'd always have a previous version of the server execution which wasn't killed properly - I'd do <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> which doesn't kill the process properly).

Try running the command `kill %1` or another to completely get rid of the previous run of the process. This usually works for me! :) Good luck!