# How to set client port number in java?

Tags: java, serversocket

Can anyone please tell me how to set a client port numbers once the server decides to accept the connection of the client. I want the port number of client should be between 50000 to 60000.

Comment: Why do you want that? Have you read through the Javadocs for `Socket` and `ServerSocket`?

Comment: @Kayaman probably to satisfy some stupid firewall rules...

Comment: When you connect you can specify a random port in range but if it is already in use this will fail and you will have to try again.

Comment: Its for my project. But I am not able to manage that. I am using server.accept(); But I need the client port number in between 50000 to 60000. Yes I a have read those documents.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey can you tell me how to set it. Using Java

Comment: "once the server decides to accept"? It's too late then, because the client has already created its socket for sending the connection request. So the client has already decided which port *it* is going to use.

Comment: @VilleOikarinen then what is the solution to it.

Comment: Solution to what? Your question embodies a contradicting in terms. No solution to those.

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking how to code the *server* in order to set the *client*'s port, then the answer is that you can't. The client chooses its own port, and that is already in use by the time the server is involved.

---

If you are asking how to code the *client* to choose a local port for a connection to the server, then the documentation for `Socket` is the place to look.

If you don't specify a port, then the OS gives an arbitrary port number from its [*ephemeral port* range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

If you do specify a local port, for example with the constructor `public Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)` then the client will attempt to bind to that local port.

However this will fail if the port is not available. The reason we typically ask the OS for an ephemeral port is to avoid "address in use" failures when two instances of the same client, or when a socket remains in `TIME_WAIT` status.

There is no API that lets you ask the OS for an ephemeral port in a given range.

The best you can do is to ask for an arbitrary port, and retry in a loop until you get one that's in your desired range:

```
 Socket socket;
 do {
    socket = new Socket();
    socket.bind(null); // null means any local address, ephemeral port
 } while (! isInRange(socket.getLocalPort());
 socket.connect(...);
```

The inefficiency of this is obvious; you could create and discard any number of sockets before stumbling on an acceptable one. It's a reasonable approach if your desired range is a good sized chunk of the OS's ephemeral range.

Alternatively you can loop through your acceptable range, catching bind errors and retrying:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    for ( int port = MIN_PORT ; port <= MAX_PORT; port++ )
    {
        try {
            s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
            break;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
            // try the next port
        }
        // deal with not having found a suitable port
    }
    socket.connect(...);
```

This has different inefficiencies, which would become especially relevant if the client runs frequently and concurrently. You'd constantly be "fighting" over the ports in the lower end of the range. If you must use this approach, it would be worth amending it to at least start looking at a random position within the range.

---

If your motivation to do this is to get around a firewall rule, try hard to get the (stupid, pointless) firewall rule fixed. However, there are clients in the wild that do use the approach I've described, because sometimes the firewall admin just won't give up.

Comment: Very good but the socket bind loop leaks sockets. They need closing in the failure case.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you need is

```
public Socket(InetAddress address,
              int port,
              InetAddress localAddr,
              int localPort)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket-java.net.InetAddress-int-java.net.InetAddress-int-

This method allows you to give a specific source port. You can chose one at random and retry if it's already taken.

Comment: Here is some code to determine the port: http://stackoverflow.com/a/116113/1838233

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I have posted my code can you tell me, how should I proceed