# How to uniquely identify a java process after multiple restart

Tags: java, service, process

I have number of java process running on my machine. I need to track how many times each process is getting restarted.

For Example:
Let us consider two java process
Process 1 - Its restarted for 5 times.
Process 2 - Its restarted for 2 times.

I'm able to get the PID, java command of the running processes. But I could not able to differentiate once the process got restarted. Because the PID changed after the restart. Also I can't consider the java command because two instance of same application which has same command.

So what are the other ways to track the java process restart ?

Comment: I thought PID is the answer. What defines an existing or a new process in your problem?
The same java command run multiple times will result in different PIDs

Comment: What does _and based on that i will be doing the update/save_ mean?

Comment: One always gets a new (random) PID when a new process (`java -jar port.jar`) is begun.  There is nothing else.  I don't understand how you expect to update a process instead of save.  Your question makes no sense.  You might be able to salvage this question by giving us more information.  Please add much more detail about what you are actually trying to do.  Otherwise there is no solution.

Comment: Sorry, Previously I was not able to explain my question clearly.
So I have modified my question.

This is what i am trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You want your processes to keep the same identity after a restart. Ideally, you would have a parameter, system property or environment variable telling the process its identity.

As you state in the question, this identity cannot be passed on the command line. Thus, the process has to "find" its identity by acquiring an exclusive resource.

This resource could be a shared system implementing locks but it is probably to complex.

As exclusive resources, we have network sockets. So you could make your processes artificially opening a socket in the sole objective to make it acquire an identity.

You can use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/116113/2242270 in order to open a socket in a range. The identity of the process is then the port that could be opened.

Comment: Thanks lbovet,
But I think this won't work on my case. Because I will be tracking all the java processes in my machine.
And also i will not be changing anything internally in the java processes.
So please suggest few more approaches.

Comment: Tell us more about how the processes are restarted. Do you have a script? This is where we could propagate the identity.

Comment: Every day at a particular time my machine will get restarted. I added some of the java process as a service and the startup type is automatic. So it will automatically start after the system restart. Rest of the java process i will be starting manually.

Comment: From the above case i need to track how many times the java process gets restarted.